# While loop to if condition

Tags: algorithm2e

I would like to change my algorithm from `while` loop to if condition. Every thing will be the same except the `while` statement.  On `while` loop, change it to `r < R`. I have tried many ways, but my script missed up.

Here is my original script for the `while`

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
  \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[]{algpseudocode}

 \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Pseudo-code of Mine}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \Input{Info}
    \Output{SCORE}
            \While{$r < R$}{
            \State 
            \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth} \par
                $n\gets function(DataX, Datax1, DataX2,$ \par
                \hskip\algorithmicindent $Type, Type2)$
            \end{varwidth}
            \State $S\gets function (S)$
            \EndWhile}


        \State $SCORE \gets Trained ANN(InfoInput)$ 
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

My trying code is also to add else condition:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Pseudo-code of Mine}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \Input{Info}
    \Output{SCORE}
            \if{$r < R$}{
            \State 
            \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth} \par
                $n\gets function(DataX, Datax1, DataX2,$ \par
                \hskip\algorithmicindent $Type, Type2)$
            \end{varwidth}
            \State $S\gets function (S)$
            \Endif}


        \State $SCORE \gets Trained ANN(InfoInput)$ 

        \Else

        {
            \State 
            \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth} \par
                $n\gets function(DataX, Datax1, DataX2,$ \par
                \hskip\algorithmicindent $Type, Type2)$
            \end{varwidth}
            \State $S\gets function (S)$
            \Endif}


        \State $SCORE \gets Trained ANN(InfoInput)$ 

\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the syntax of two different algorithm packages incorrectly. It seems like you're favouring [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) for the general structure, while using an [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)-type syntax for some of the other components.

Below I've used the traditional `algorithm2e` syntax to provide you with the layout you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Some algorithm caption}

  \Input{Info}
  \Output{SCORE}

  \If{$r < R$}{
    $n \gets \text{function}(\text{DataX}, \text{DataX1}, \text{DataX2}, \text{Type}, \text{Type2})$\;
    $S \gets \text{function}(S)$\;
  }
  $\text{SCORE} \gets \text{Trained ANN}(\text{InfoInput})$\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Specifically note:

- Use a `\;` to terminate the end of an input line within the `algorithm` environment. It - the semi-colon - will be printed by default, unless you issue `\DontPrintSemicolon`.
- An **if**-statement has the syntax `\If{<cond>}{<then>}`, while an **if-else**-statement uses `\eIf{<cond>}{<then>}{<else>}`.
- There is no `\State` with `algorithm2e`.

Comment: Wow, yours works smoothly, with no errors. Other works but many errors that make other noises. Thank You, @Werner

Comment: I use {varwidth} to adjust size of that line, because without it, line will cross other text on the life, your script with {varwidth} seems unfriendly

Comment: @jou: [Here is some code](https://pastebin.com/zfdF8MKb) that shows how you can use [`varwidth`](//ctan.org/pkg/varwidth). The `varwidth` environment necessarily puts its contents in text mode (similar to `minipage`). However, since you seem to be breaking the line manually, it may suffice for you to use a `[t]`op-aligned `array`. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/zGN5h9Dd) for an example of how that can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `\If` instead of `\if`. Also I believe, the correct structure for if else statements is `\If{<condition>} <text> \Else <text> \Endif`. You appear to have `\If{<condition>}{<text> \Endif} \Else{<text> \Endif}`.

Something like:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Pseudo-code of Mine}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{Info}
\Output{SCORE}
     \If{$r < R$}
        \State 
        \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth} \par
            $n\gets function(DataX, Datax1, DataX2,$ \par
            \hskip\algorithmicindent $Type, Type2)$
        \end{varwidth}
        \State $S\gets function (S)$



    \State $SCORE \gets Trained ANN(InfoInput)$ 

    \Else


        \State 
        \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth} \par
            $n\gets function(DataX, Datax1, DataX2,$ \par
            \hskip\algorithmicindent $Type, Type2)$
        \end{varwidth}
        \State $S\gets function (S)$
     \Endif


    \State $SCORE \gets Trained ANN(InfoInput)$ 

\end{algorithm}
```

I can't be sure, though because you are trying to use three different algorithm packages. I suggest you pick one and only include that one.

Comment: The syntax you're using here is not correct; it mixes the use of [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) and aren't truly compatible.

Comment: I just copied the OP's code and fixed the If statements. The OP was already mixing styles.